# Get around subprocess not getting reply?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, nonblocking

I have a daemon which is querying hardware and taking action based on responses. I have noticed that there is a tiny chance that I get do get a reply and my daemon starts a new instance of itself, for some reason.

This is because my code is blocking due to `communicate()` and it never gets a reply so never returns.

```
 ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
 out = ps.communicate()
 return out
```

In what way could I avoid this problem? I am using `2.7` on `linux`, I see  `3.3+` has timeout available in `subprocess` but I do not, any non-blocking way to do this? Signal alarms work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = ps.communicate()
print out
print err
```